# Does anyone else think instance variables are problematic in database-backed applications?

Tags: database, imperative-programming, state-management

It occurs to me that state control in languages like C# is not well supported.

By this, I mean, it is left upto the programmer to manage the state of in-memory objects. A common use-case is that instance variables in the domain-model are copies of information residing in persistent storage (i.e. the database). Clearly this violates the single point of authority principle, and "synchronisation" has to be managed by the developer.

I envisage a system where instead of instance variables, we have simple public access/mutator methods marked with attributes that link them to the database, and where reads and writes are mediated by a framework that decides whether to hit the database. Does such a system exist?

Am I completely missing the point, or is there some truth to this idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand correctly what you want: Any OR-Mapper with Lazy Loading is working this way. For example i use [Genome](http://www.genom-e.com) and there every entity is a pure proxy and you have quite much influence to tell the OR-Mapper how to cache the fields.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there's the concept of data prevalence (as implemented by [prevayler](http://www.prevayler.org/) in Java) where the in-memory objects are the single point of authority (SPA) for the data.

Also, some object databases (as [db4o](http://www.db4o.com/)) blur lines a bit between the object representation and the "store" representation.

On the other hand, by bringing the SPA for the data inside the application, you need to handle transactions and/or data persistence by yourself. There is some work done on transactional memory systems such as [JVSTM](http://web.ist.utl.pt/~joao.cachopo/jvstm/) (currently in use by the information system of my old college) but it's not in widespread use.

On the other hand, if the data lives in a database, you can just commit the data when everything is good (or use the support for transactions built in the database) and be sure that data isn't corrupted or lost. You trade in the SPA principle for better data reliability and transactions (and other advantages of using a separate data store)